Ip adress tracing lost coins
I read in bitcoin.org that bitcoin is peer to peer means can be traced by ip address.
Actually I don't recall I did join bitcoin but maybe I have these thoughts that could have earned some during my many daily done once activities ... just to clear thoughts that's my ip address 197.52.35.129 .so can u locate any funds I had and forgot about

It is not possible to locate, prove ownership and gain control of Bitcoins from an IP address.

OK thank you...
